# Moving a node as the first child of another node

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a document:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <style>some styles<style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Header</h1>
   <table>table content</table>
   <div>some text</div>
 </body>
</A>
```

The below code moves the `<style>` tag below the `<div>` in `<body>`:

```
  style  = @doc.at_css "style"
  body = @doc.at_css "body"
  style.parent = body
```

Is there a way to move `<style>` above `<h1>`?

Answer (score 3):

Finding the first child of the body and adding the style tag as previous sibling to first child solves the problem.

```
  style  = @doc.at_css "style"
  body = @doc.at_css "body"
  style.parent = body

  first_child = body.first_element_child
  first_child.add_previous_sibling(style)
```